# validation error using max file size in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am having some trouble uploading a file - excel file.

I am using this rule in laravel 5.5 for max file size 3MB. According to the documentation the value must be in KB.

```
// Max file size: 3MB (3000 KB)
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Feed' => 'file|max:3000',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['File to big!']);
    }
```

In php.ini i have:

```
upload_max_filesize=3M
```

The file which i want to upload is 2.3 MB.

What i did wrong on validation?

***UPDATE***

Displaying the $_FILES['Feed'] for the file that i want to upload (original.xls = 2.3MB)

```
array:5 [
 "name" => "original.xls"
 "type" => ""
 "tmp_name" => ""
 "error" => 1
 "size" => 0
]
```

"error" => 1

and upload another small file 5.6 KB:

```
array:5 [
 "name" => "test.xls"
 "type" => "application/vnd.ms-excel"
 "tmp_name" => "/tmp/phpJUJfy4"
 "error" => 0
 "size" => 5632
]
```

"error" => 0 and i can see the size for it

***UPDATE 2***

If i start to delete from the excel file and get max: 2MB, the file uploads with no errors.

Why? 2.0 MB uploads the file and 2.1 MB NOT???

Comment: Have you seen any error?

Comment: yes....the error that i returned: "File to big!"

Comment: Have you tried with only 'Feed' => 'max:3000',

Comment: Check the errors returned in the validator itself.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin the validator itself: "The feed failed to upload." and tried only with max:3000 and the same error

Comment: @calin24 maybe the problem is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432948/5704410 `max:10240 = max 10 MB`?

Comment: according to that thread: 500000 KB != 500 KB... does not make sense why is using 500000 for 500KB !!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in php.ini

On my server (ubuntu 18.04) i am using php 7.1 and changed the

```
upload_max_filesize=3M
```

only from apache2/php.ini file from:

```
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
```

When i changed in the other one (cli) now works:

```
/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

When file send to server a browser use MIME encoding to convert all non-printable bytes to printable chars. This encoding increase file size.

So, when you send 2.3Mb file its actual size become more than 3Mb.