# Laravel set max upload size limit for specific routes?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I want to change `upload_max_filesize` only for specific routes. But as in `PHP` > 5.3 ini_set() will not work for setting the limits from the script. Is there any workaround?

**UPDATE**

In a specified route, I have to check the upload file size based on user's subscription plan. In other routes I don't have access to user's info and/or I don't want to check file size for every other route, e.g. login route. And because the server's default upload size is very large, someone may intentionally post very large files and cause wasting server's resources.

Comment: I comment this as this is just a suggestion. What if you combine [file size validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432641/how-to-validate-on-max-file-size-in-laravel) with middleware on routes. So you check it in your code instead of server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is using validator:

for set max size use

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'max:500000',
]);
```

The value is in kilobytes. I.e. max:10240 = max 10 MB

also see:

[Laravel Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests)

And if you want use this rule for many times you can make request and add this rules there

**1.** run

```
php artisan make:request ExampleRequest
```

**2.** in app/Http/Requests select ExampleRequest

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file'=>'max:500000',
    ];
}
```

**3.** use ExampleRequest where you need instead of Request

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found that neither it's possible nor it should be done that way!

When a request with a large file attached to its body reaches the Controller/Middleware part of the framework, it has already wasted RAM, CPU and Storage of my server. So blocking the request from that point doesn't have any use.

Web servers and their respective config for website with routes that should handle large files and other routes SHOULD be separated. 
So I came up with 2 web sites,

- one allows large files and only serves those specific routes
  responsible handling large files.
- the other one for api routes and has a `upload_max_filesize` limit set to a small value.