# Input File Size & Type

Tags: laravel, validation, input

I'm new at Laravel.

How can I limit the file size to 5mb and file type in Controller?

```
public function add_presentation_detail(Request $request){
    $start_date     = $request->start_date;
    $input_file     = $request->file;

    $nik    = Sentinel::getUser()->nik;

    $data   = AccelerateMentee::select(
        'accelerate_mentee.*',
        'accelerate_rotation.start_date',
        'accelerate_rotation.id as id_rotation'
    )
    ->leftJoin('accelerate_rotation', 'accelerate_rotation.id_mentee', '=', 'accelerate_mentee.id')
    ->where([
        ['accelerate_mentee.nik', '=', $nik],
        ['accelerate_rotation.status', '<>', 'approved']
    ])
    ->first();

    if (!empty($request->file) && $request->hasFile('file')) {
        
        $filename       = $input_file->getClientOriginalName();
        $new_filename   = "presentation_" . "-" . $filename;
        $upload_file    = $input_file->storeAs('public/accelerate/',$new_filename);

    } else {

        $new_filename = null;

    }
    $update = AccelerateRotation::where('id', '=', $data->id_rotation)
    ->update([
        'status'            => 'submitted',
        'panel_time_start'  => $start_date,
        'file'              => $new_filename,
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope u guys answer my question, I'm really confused. Thank u so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432641/how-to-validate-on-max-file-size-in-laravel

Comment: From the [max: value](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-max) validation rule: "_The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum value. Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule._"